# PHP Script fopen failed to open stream: > Invalid argument Error

Tags: php, fopen

I am getting a warning.

> Warning: fopen(76561197992146126 .txt): failed to open stream:
>   Invalid argument in C:\wamp\www\Download\t3.php on line 6

For anyone wondering, this is the contents of main.txt below (http://pastebin.com/53chSRRz)

```
<?php
    $APIkey = 'APIKeyHere';
    $file = file('C:\wamp\www\Download\main.txt');
    foreach ($file as $link) { 
    $link2 = "http://api.steampowered.com/ITFItems_440/GetPlayerItems/v0001/?key=" . $APIkey . "&SteamID=" . $link . "&format=json";
    $downloaded = file_get_contents($link2);
    $fh = fopen($link . ".txt", "a"); //or die("can't open file");
    fwrite($fh, $downloaded);
    }
    echo "Finished";
?>
```

If I replace "fopen($link . ".txt", "a")" with a static file-name it works. But I need $link to be the filename. It is imperative to my setup.

I am running Windows 7 x64 using WAMP 2.2 with PHP 5.4.3

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your link IDs have whitespace in them. Try adding `$link = trim($link);` before creating `$link2`.

Comment: HOLY effing crap. You have NO idea how long I have spent on this to have that tiny line fix it. Thanks SO much xD